# Use of delete in union(x, y) in a BinomialHeap implementation

Tags: c++, memory, heap

I'd like to get some advice on best practises for deallocating memory for data structures, using the BinomialHeap as an example. According to the 'Union' section in this link, as well as many other sources,

[http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap20.htm](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ecsli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap20.htm)

the method union(Heap x, Heap y) will destroy x and y, but not the lists to which they point.

From a logical perspective, however, I wonder if how best to implement this in C++. I understand I can write a destructor like so ..

```
class BinomialHeap{
public:
    Node* head;
    int size;
    ~BinomialHeap() { head = nullptr; };
  // other methods
};
```

then deleting it within Union(x, y), to deallocate memory, like so ...

```
Heap* BinomialHeap::Union(Heap* x, Heap* y) {     // assume x and y, and all their nodes, were dynamically allocated
   Node* x_head = x->head;
   Node* y_head = y->head;
   delete x;
   delete y;
   // code to merge x_head with y_head
};
```

... would leave the head node in x itself untouched. Despite this, I wonder if it's smart design to
write a destructor, which (in my mind) should conceptually free up all memory associated with the object, in this way. If not, would it perhaps be better to write a method like the following?

```
class BinomialHeap{
private:
    void union_delete();
   // other code
};

void BinomialHeap::union_delete() {
    head = nullptr;
    delete this;
};
```

I understand the issues with calling delete this, but with my limited experience in using BinomialHeap "in the real world", I can't imagine a case outside of hacking where, as long as I hold some reference to the head_nodes (head_x, head_y) prior to deleting the heaps, that this method shouldn't exist.

I hope the answer isn't "depends on what you're working on/who's using the class/etc, etc.", but what would one consider "standard practise" in dealing with this type of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd say always use RAII for resource cleanup -- preferably through a `std::unique_ptr` rather than using manual `delete` invocation.

From the way the `Union` operation is described, I don't think it has to *actually* destroy the object in the `delete` sense, but rather "destructively mutate" by stealing the contents. This is effectively the way that C++'s "move-semantics" work. After the operation, the object still exists, but has no resources to clean up.

To describe what I mean, I'll use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) from C++11 which always wraps resource cleanup in RAII.

```cpp
class Heap
{
public:
    // Move two heaps to create a 'Union' of two heaps
    static Heap Union(Heap&& lhs, Heap&& rhs);
    // ...
private:
    // unique_ptr ensures it gets deleted when destructed
    std::unique_ptr<Node> m_head;
};

Heap Heap::Union(Heap&& left, Heap&& right)
{
    // destructively mutate 'left' and 'right'; but we don't have to "destroy" 'left' and 'right'
    auto l = std::move(lhs.m_head);
    auto r = std::move(rhs.m_head):

    // create the new 'Heap' from the above and return it
};
```

In such a case, we aren't actually "destroying" the object, so much as gutting it and leaving it for death. This is also effectively the same concept behind "move-semantics" in C++.

The use of this code would then be:

```cpp
auto a = /* Heap A */
auto b = /* Heap B */
auto c = Heap::Union( std::move(a), std::move(b) );

// 'a' and 'b' still exist (aren't destroyed) but no longer contain any data.
```

Comment: Okay, I've executed your code, and I see how the use of std::move can conceptually "destructively mutate" 2 heaps. Also, it's clear that the onus is on the class user to "remember" that although a and b physically exist after````Union````, they, for all intents and purposes, may as well not. Thank you for your perspective.